# SSRS report description character limit

Tags: reporting-services, character, limit

The Description property field of an SSRS report accepts a text description that appears when a user clicks the "..." in the upper right corner of the deployed report's tile displayed on the report server.  What's the exact limit on the number of characters that can be placed in the Description property?  Trial & error suggests it's about 425 characters, but I'd like to know exactly.  It's frustrating that you can [apparently] put as many characters as you like in the Description property field without getting a warning until you deploy the report, at which point you may get a "The Description field has a value that is not valid" message.  I chased my tail for a while trying to figure out if I had put an illegal character the Description property field, until I realized that the message was probably telling me that I had exceeded the character limit--but what's the actual limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 512

The Description field has a length of 512 characters in the Catalog table of ReportServer but the SSRS property will let you enter any number of characters without error.

[image]

When A report is deployed to a report server with more than 512 characters, it gives an error:

> The Description field has a value that is not valid.

On the other hand, if you **change** the Description Property and deploy the report over a current report, the Description field IS NOT UPDATED and it does deploy.

Comment: Hannover: Thanks very much for your reply.  I'll try to do some experiments to figure out why my deployments generated errors with Descriptions well under 512 characters (at least I "think" they did).  I may just wind up proving that my own recollection is faulty.  I'll report back and accept your answer once I've figured things out at my end.

Comment: Yup--my experiments confirm that you're right.  Problem at my end was failing to include spaces in counting characters in my descriptions--duh!